# Can anyone identify this uncaptioned diagram?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula

[image]

It's from the start of part 3 / chapter 19 in Lewin's Genes X (see [this page in Google Books](http://goo.gl/ThZu7t))...

Looks a bit like a Ramachandran plot(?) but the axes only go to 100 / 70ish, but I don't even know what molecule it is since it doesn't say and there's no image attribution page at the front/back.

Any sleuths out there?

Comment: You could of course always [contact](http://www.cincinnatichildrens.org/bio/m/jun-ma/) the creator of this image.

Comment: Also, sometimes books contain figure information in other locations other than the page the figure appears on.  This can appear in neighboring pages or sometimes in a section at the beginning or end of the book.

Comment: Why do you think that it is molecule? I guess it is ribosome, considering kind of one bigger one smaller parts aggregation.